# How do I access Amazon Sagemaker through React Native?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, mobile, amazon-sagemaker

I am currently using react-native to build a mobile application. I need to access a machine learning model in order to send pictures for segmentation. I want to be able to receive a segmented picture back to have the background of the picture cut out. I am trying to use Amazon Sagemaker (because it seems to be a easy to work with package, but if there are other ways to do it, please let me know).

On [this](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/?sc_icampaign=pac-sagemaker-console-tutorial&sc_ichannel=ha&sc_icontent=awssm-2276&sc_iplace=console-body&trk=ha_awssm-2276) Sagemaker quick-start guide, on step 5a, it states:

> 5a. To deploy the model on a server and create an endpoint that you can access, copy the following code into the next code cell and select Run:
>   xgb_predictor = xgb.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')

I want to host everything on AWS and not have to run a separate server. What service/process could I use that would allow me to create an endpoint that I can access through react-native?

Comment: Do you already have a model for cleaning out the background, or do you want also to develop one on SageMaker? The example above is for XGBoost and not for image processing.

Comment: @Guy I thought that XGBoost was just an algorithm that aided an existing algorithm, but looking into it, that is not the case. I do not have a model for cleaning the background, but my idea is to somehow create an image that is created from a mask returned by the [Tensorflow image segmentation model] (https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/images/segmentation#next_steps). Will that work?

Comment: sure. If you are able to train that model, and you are able to create a Docker image of that algorithm/model, you will be able to deploy it to SageMaker. Once it is deployed to SageMaker serving service, you can use the SDK of AWS (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) to call the endpoint with the API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SageMakerRuntime.html#invokeEndpoint-property. Not simple, but possible.

Comment: @Guy Thanks! I am new to API calls and this process in general so I'm not sure how this works. What would the SDK be used for? You mentioned that I need it to to call the endpoint with the API. Does that meant that the "invokeEndpoint" command be in the SDK, or is there something in the SDK that I need to use the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the conversation in the comments:

Once you have your model trained, tuned, and deployed (which is not a simple process), you can call the endpoint of the model using the [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js), that you install by:

```
npm install aws-sdk
var AWS = require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native');
```

you include in the HTML as:

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.538.0.min.js"></script>
```

And when you want to call the endpoint you invoke it like that:

```
var params = {
  Body: Buffer.from('...') || 'STRING_VALUE' /* Strings will be Base-64 encoded on your behalf */, /* required */
  EndpointName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Accept: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ContentType: 'STRING_VALUE',
  CustomAttributes: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
sagemakerruntime.invokeEndpoint(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

You can check out the [Amplify Library](https://aws-amplify.github.io) that can take some of the heavy liftings such as getting IAM permissions to call the API, a user log in and many others.